# What is the Arctangent of Tangent?

Tags: trigonometry

This is probably just me misunderstanding trig properties. I remember from my trig days that $\tan(\arctan(x)) = x$ But I can't remember if that holds the other way. Can someone help me out? Is this valid:

$$\arctan(\tan(\theta)) = \theta$$

Comment: Just saying, the arctan of an angle is meaningless.

Comment: $\theta$ is a variable not exclusively reserved for angles.

Comment: @Zxu You're right that was just laziness on my part. I've edited, to make it clear that I'm not talking about an angle.

Comment: simple solution... draw a graph of the tangent function. Then draw the arctan function on both an x-y graph and a y-x graph.

Comment: @JohnJoy Yeah Rohan demonstrates that in his answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2116642/194115http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2116642/194115

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is true that $\tan\arctan x=x$, for every $x$. The converse is not true and it cannot be, because the tangent is not an injective function.

Recall that $\arctan x$ returns a number (an angle if you prefer) in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. So we have the equality
$$
\arctan(\tan\theta)=\theta
$$
if and only if $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

A formula can be given for any $\theta$: you just need to “reduce” the angle to the right interval by subtracting an integral multiple of $\pi$ so that
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta-k\pi<\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
-\frac{1}{2}<\frac{\theta}{\pi}-k<\frac{1}{2}
$$
or
$$
0<\frac{\theta}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}-k<1
$$
or
$$
k<\frac{\theta}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}<k+1
$$
which means
$$
k=\left\lfloor\frac{\theta}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
Thus
$$
\arctan(\tan\theta)=\theta-\pi\left\lfloor\frac{\theta}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
(of course when $\tan\theta$ is defined to begin with).

For instance, if $\theta=15\pi/4$, we have
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{\theta}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=
\left\lfloor\frac{15}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor=4
$$
and
$$
\arctan\tan\frac{15\pi}{4}=\frac{15\pi}{4}-4\pi=-\frac{\pi}{4}
$$

Comment: I think that I understand everything here, except for why you're taking the floor. What's that about?

Comment: @JonathanMee If $k<x<k+1$, then $k=\lfloor x\rfloor$, we need to find $k$.

Comment: Arctan(Tan( is a Beautiful way of representing Floor function

Comment: @egreg: if theta = 2.5*pi, then arctan(tan(2.5pi))=pi/2.  The equality provided yields -pi/2. Check use of ceiling vs. floor function.

Comment: @926reals If $\theta=5\pi/2$, then $\tan\theta$ is not defined.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for answering.  I see tan(5pi/2)=1/0 -> undefined.  In approximation we have: limit as x->0 of (1/x) = +infinity; likewise, limit as x->-0 (1/x) = -infinity.  We also have that Arctan(+infinity) = pi/2 and Arctan(-infinity)= -pi/2.  In order to consolidate, I grapple the ceiling and floor functions. What I come across is that the following equation provides the correct solution: Arctan(tan(x))=x-pi*ceiling(x/pi-1/2).

Comment: @926reals The problem is always at $\pi/2+k\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2$.

No, otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

It only equals $\theta $ if $$-\frac {\pi}{2}<\theta < \frac {\pi}{2} $$ as the range of $\arctan$ is only from $-\frac {\pi}{2} $ to $\frac {\pi}{2} $. If $\theta $ is outside this interval, then you would need to add or subtract $\pi $ from $\theta $ until you get to the angle in this interval that has the same value of $\tan$.

For instance, $\arctan (\tan \frac {\pi}{6}) = \frac {\pi}{6} $, but $\arctan (\tan \frac {3\pi }{4}) = -\frac {\pi}{4} $.

This can also been seen here:

[image] Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

All you can say *a priori* is
$$\arctan(\tan\theta)\equiv \theta\mod\pi.$$

Comment: Just checking here, you meant mod π/2 right?

Comment: Not at all. The tangent function has period π.