# Defining a repeating series with a simple expression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, closed-form

I'm looking for a simple expression with which I can define a repeating series.

$$f(0)=0$$
$$f(1)=1$$
$$f(2)=2$$
$$f(3)=3$$
$$f(4)=f(n-4)$$

So, the series goes $0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3...$ and on and on. I feel like this should have something to do with exponents because in Discrete Math we figured out how to define a series that goes $1, -1, 1, -1...$ but I'm not sure how to even begin defining this.

I don't want anything recursive if I can possibly avoid it. Not sure if that will be a problem.

Thanks a bunch!

**EDIT:** Spoke to a professor about how to solve this and he says there is a way to do it involving only +/-/*/^/÷, but it involves complex numbers.

Comment: _[Closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)_ expression or formula is the usual term for what you are looking for, if I understood correctly. Anyway, in the end, the best way to define something depends on what your are going to use it for. :-)

Comment: Maybe of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073606/is-there-a-one-line-function-that-generates-a-triangle-wave or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116622/what-is-the-arctangent-of-tangent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add an alternative to the other answers: you can use generating functions to try to find an explicit solution to the recurrence relation. If $F(x)$ is the generating function for the sequence $f(n)$,

$$F(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}f(n)x^n=f(0)+f(1)x+f(2)x^2+f(3)x^3+\cdots$$

then from the recurrence given by

$$\begin{cases}f(0)=0\\f(1)=1\\f(2)=2\\f(3)=3\\f(n)=f(n-4)&\text{for }n\ge4\end{cases}$$

we have

$$\begin{align*}
f(n-4)&=f(n)\\
\sum_{n\ge4}f(n-4)x^n&=\sum_{n\ge4}f(n)x^n\\
x^4\sum_{n\ge4}f(n-4)x^{n-4}&=\sum_{n\ge0}f(n)x^n-f(0)-f(1)x-f(2)x^2-f(3)x^3\\
x^4\sum_{n\ge0}f(n)x^n&=F(x)-x-2x^2-3x^3\\
x^4F(x)&=F(x)-x-2x^2-3x^3\\
(x^4-1)F(x)&=-x-2x^2-3x^3\\
F(x)&=\frac{x+2x^2+3x^3}{1-x^4}
\end{align*}$$

Expanding into partial fractions, you have

$$F(x)=\frac32\frac1{1-x}-\frac12\frac1{1+x}-\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac x{1+x^2}$$

and expressing each term as a power series we arrive at

$$\begin{align*}
F(x)&=\frac32\sum_{n\ge0}x^n-\frac12\sum_{n\ge0}(-x)^n-\sum_{n\ge0}(-x^2)^n-x\sum_{n\ge0}(-x^2)^n\\
F(x)&=\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\frac32-\frac12(-1)^n\right)x^n-\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^nx^{2n}-\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}
\end{align*}$$

each of which are valid for $|x|<1$.

Now,

$$\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\frac32-\frac12(-1)^n\right)x^n=1+2x+x^2+2x^3+\cdots$$
$$\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^nx^{2n}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots$$
$$\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}=x-x^3+x^5-x^7+\cdots$$

so it follows that

$$F(x)=\color{lightgray}{0+}\,x+2x^2+3x^3+\color{lightgray}{0x^4+}\,x^5+2x^6+3x^7+\cdots$$

Replace $n=k$ in the latter two series, then split up the first into the even and odd cases, letting $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1$, respectively, so that the generating function can be expressed as

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sum_{k\ge0}(1-(-1)^k)x^{2k}&n=2k\text{ is even}\\[1ex]
\displaystyle\sum_{k\ge0}(2-(-1)^k)x^{2k+1}&n=2k+1\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

From this it follows that a closed form for $f(n)$ can be obtained by splitting into even/odd cases:

$$f(n)_{n\ge0}=\begin{cases}1-(-1)^{n/2}&n\text{ is even}\\2-(-1)^{(n-1)/2}&n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

If I'm not mistaken, there should be a way to get an "even more explicit" form in terms of complex exponentials, but perhaps this result will suffice for your needs.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was thinking with fractions in the exponents. I am going to swing by a study group and see if I can't find the answer with complex numbers, because I think that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: With Mathematica, I find the solution in terms of complex numbers to be$$f(n)=\frac32-\frac12(-1)^n-\frac{1+i}2(-i)^n-\frac{1-i}2i^n$$Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

You could just write
$$
f(n) = n \pmod{4}
$$
( a loose use of notation but perfectly clear)
or
$$
f(n) = n -  4 \lfloor n/4 \rfloor .
$$

I think the first would be kinder to your reader.

Comment: [here's a wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) explaining modular arithmetic for OP.

Comment: I am familiar with modular arithmetic :) I was more thinking a traditional expression without using different counting systems, but this works too.

Comment: Another version of this is $f(n) = (n\bmod4),$ in which $\bmod$ is a binary operation. In several programming languages this is implemented as the `%` operator, `n % 4.` It's really just an ordinary operation on ordinary integers, not having anything to do with $\mathbb Z_4$ or any other such esoteric domains.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something along the lines of $(-1)^n$
(which produces $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$),
first consider
$$ f_1(n) = \tfrac12\left(1 - (-1)^n\right),$$
which implies that $f_1(n) = 0,1,0,1,\ldots$ for $n = 0,1,2,3,\ldots.$

### Example 1

We can slow down the rate of alternation of $f_1$
by making the exponent grow slower:
$$ f_2(n) = \tfrac12\left(1 - (-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\right),$$
where $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal
to $n/2.$ This function follows the pattern
$f_2(n) = 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,\ldots$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\ldots.$

Put this together in the form $f(n) = f_1(n) + 2f_2(n)$ and you have the function you asked for. That is, let
$$
f(n) = \tfrac32 - \tfrac12(-1)^n - (-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}.
$$

### Example 2

If you don't like the greatest-integer function 
(used in the expression $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$), we can work around this
by fiddling with sinusoidal functions.
Let $g_1(n) = \cos\left(\frac12 n\pi - \frac14\pi\right),$ so that 
$\newcommand{s}{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}
 g_1(n) = \s,\s,-\s,-\s,\s,\s,-\s,-\s,\ldots$ 
for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\ldots.$
Then let
\begin{align}
f(n) &= f_1(n) + 1 - \sqrt2g_1(n) \\
&= \tfrac32 - \tfrac12(-1)^n
      - \sqrt2\cos\left(\tfrac12 n\pi - \tfrac14\pi\right).
\end{align}

### Example 3

If you're willing to use complex numbers, notice that
$\cos z = \tfrac12\left(e^{iz} + e^{-iz}\right).$
Using the function notation $\exp(z) = e^z$ to make the first equation below more readable, we get
\begin{align}
\cos\left(\tfrac12 n\pi - \tfrac14\pi\right) &=
\tfrac12 \left(\exp\left(i\left(\tfrac12 n\pi - \tfrac14\pi\right)\right)
      + \exp\left(-i\left(\tfrac12 n\pi - \tfrac14\pi\right)\right)\right)\\
&= \tfrac12 \left(e^{in\pi/2} e^{-i\pi/4} + e^{-in\pi/2} e^{i\pi/4}\right)\\
&= \tfrac12 e^{i\pi/4} \left(e^{in\pi/2} e^{-i\pi/2} + e^{-in\pi/2}\right).
\end{align}

Then, using the facts that $e^{i\pi/2}=i,$ $e^{-i\pi/2}=-i,$
and $e^{i\pi/4}=\tfrac{\sqrt2}{2}(1+i),$
\begin{align}
\cos\left(\tfrac12 n\pi + \tfrac14\pi\right)
&= \tfrac12\left(\tfrac{\sqrt2}{2}(1+i)\right)\left(i^n(-i)+(-i)^n\right)\\
&= \tfrac{\sqrt2}{4}(1+i) \left((-1)^n - i\right) i^n.
\end{align}

It follows that
$$
f(n) = \tfrac32 - \tfrac12(-1)^n - \tfrac12(1+i)\left((-1)^n - i\right)i^n.
$$

And indeed the right-hand side is also equal to
$\tfrac32-\tfrac12(-1)^n-\tfrac12(1+i)(-i)^n-\tfrac12(1-i)i^n,$
an expression that was given in a comment under another answer.

---

Frankly, I think any of the preceding examples is far clumsier than Ethan Bolker's formula $n -  4 \lfloor n/4 \rfloor,$ which is inspired by modular arithmetic but actually uses only ordinary integer arithmetic with the 
greatest-integer function.
That answer gets my vote.

---

### Example 4

I have added this example after seeing that the accepted answer uses
a curly bracket with multiple cases ($n$ odd and $n$ even)
on the right-hand side of the equation.
If two cases are OK, why not four? That is,
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
  0 \quad & n = 4k, k \in \mathbb Z \\
  1 & n = 4k+1, k \in \mathbb Z \\
  2 & n = 4k+2, k \in \mathbb Z \\
  3 & n = 4k+3, k \in \mathbb Z \\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer involving only $+,-,\times,\div$ and exponentiation and using complex numbers. It is based upon the $r$-th *[roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)* $\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij}{r}\right), 0\leq j<r$.

Recall the following holds true for natural numbers $n,r>0$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij n}{r}\right)=
\begin{cases}
1&\qquad r\mid n\\
0& \qquad otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

> Since the sequence 
>   \begin{align*}
> (0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,\ldots)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   has period $4$ we set $r=4$ and consider the sequence
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^3\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ijn}{4}\right)\right)_{n\geq 0}=(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,\ldots)
> \end{align*}
>   which has a $1$ at each $4$-th position and $0$ otherwise.

We use this sequence as *basic building block* to generate the wanted sequence (1).

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(0,1,}&\color{blue}{2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,0,1,2,3\ldots)}\\
> &=(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,\ldots)\\
> &\qquad+2(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,\ldots)\\
> &\qquad+3(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,\ldots)\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^3\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij(n-1)}{4}\right)\right)_{n\geq 0}
> +2\left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^3\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij(n-2)}{4}\right)\right)_{n\geq 0}\\
> &\qquad+3\left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^3\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij(n-3)}{4}\right)\right)_{n\geq 0}\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{4}\left[1+\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i(n-1)}{4}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i(n-1)}{4}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{6\pi i(n-1)}{4}\right)\right]\right.\\
> &\quad+\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i(n-2)}{4}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i(n-2)}{4}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{6\pi i(n-2)}{4}\right)\right]\\
> &\quad+\left.\frac{3}{4}\left[1+\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i(n-3)}{4}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i(n-3)}{4}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{6\pi i(n-3)}{4}\right)\right]\right)_{n\geq 0}\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{4}\left[1+i^n(-i)+(-1)^n(-1)+(-i)^n\cdot i\right]\right.\\
> &\quad+\frac{1}{2}\left[1+i^n(-1)+(-1)^n\cdot 1+(-i)^n(-1)\right]\\
> &\quad+\left.\frac{3}{4}\left[1+i^n\cdot i+(-1)^n(-1)+(-i)^n(-i)\right]\right)_{n\geq 0}\\
> &=\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}\right)+i^n\left(-\frac{1}{4}i-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}i\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\left.+(-1)^n\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4}\right)+(-i)^n\left(\frac{1}{4}i-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4}i\right)\right)_{n\geq 0}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\left(\frac{3-(-1)^n}{2}-i^n\cdot\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}+i^{n+1}\cdot\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}\right)_{n\geq 0}}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* Some instructive examples can be found in H.S. Wilf's book *[generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)*, (2.4.5) to (2.4.9).

Answer (score 0):

For integer values of $x$ this: $J\left(x\right)=1-\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\cdot 2\cdot x\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\cdot 2\cdot x\right)\right)+\frac{\left(1-\left(-1\right)^x\right)}{2}$ works.